# Prevent gradient descent from stopping too far from a local minimum

Tags: python, gradient-descent

I'm implementing an algorithm in Python to find the nearest minimum of a 2-dimensional function using the [gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) method. It takes a precision interval *eps* as input and stops when the distance between the initial and newly-found point on a given iteration is lesser than *eps*. The code at that stage looked like this:

```
while(slow_steps <= 4):
        lbd_current = lbd(x_current)
        x_previous = x_current.copy()
        grad = normalized_gradient(f_multi, x_previous)
        x_current = [x_previous[i] + lbd_current * grad[i] for i in range(len(x_previous))]
        x_list.append(x_current.copy())
        iteration += 1
        if(distance(x_previous, x_current) <= eps):
            slow_steps += 1
```

However, I encountered a problem with the initial version of the algorithm: it frequently got stuck in 'valleys' such as [this one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+100+*+%28y+-+x+%5E+2%29+%5E+2+%2B+%281+-+x%29+%5E+2+from+x%3D-11+to+-9%2C+y%3D99+to+101), depending on the function.

So far I have attempted to add a second step to traverse valleys: if the algorithm detects that the descent is slow, instead of ending immediately, it takes the points found on the latest and third-to-latest iterations and finds the nearest low point on the line between those, a line that hopefully aligns with the direction of the valley.

```
        if(distance(x_previous, x_current) <= eps * 10 and canyon_steps >= 3):
            x_canyon = x_list[len(x_list) - 2]
            vector_canyon = [x_current[i] - x_canyon[i] for i in range(len(x_canyon))]
            lbd_current = lbd_canyon()
            x_current = [x_canyon[i] + vector_canyon[i] * lbd_current for i in range(len(x_canyon))]
            if(distance(x_previous, x_current) > eps):
                canyon_steps = 0
                slow_steps = 0
        if(distance(x_previous, x_current) <= eps * 10):
            canyon_steps += 1
```

This algorithm works for most starting positions that I've tried, but for others, such as [this one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+100+*+%28y+-+x+%5E+2%29+%5E+2+%2B+%281+-+x%29+%5E+2+from+x%3D99+to+101%2C+y%3D999+to+1001), it fails if the precision is low and seems to take a very long time to finish otherwise. How can I ensure that the algorithm arrives at a local minimum with as good chances as possible?